# FFMPEG : snapshots are not immediately generated but have "delay"

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow, snapshot

I'm using FFMPEG to capture a live stream from a directshow device (here a VGA2USB adapter).

I need to generate snapshot on scene change which I manage to do with the following command line :

```
ffmpeg -v verbose -r 20 -f dshow -rtbufsize 2000M -i "video=VGA2USB V2U115452" -s 1024x768 -pix_fmt yuv420p -filter:v yadif=2:0:0 -vcodec mjpeg -muxdelay 0.1 -f image2 -vf select='gt(scene\,0.1)' -vsync vfr "c:\tmp\image%3d.jpg"
```

This command line generates the snapshot but they are "delayed". I mean, when a scene change is detected with the filter, the previous snapshot is written in the jpg file and the current stay in "buffer" (or whereever it is).

If I try to generate a snapshot every 5 seconds (with -vf fps=fps=1/5 option) the first snapshot is written on the hard disk at the 5th second.

How can I force FFMPEG to write immediately the snapshot and not to wait the next snapshot ?
Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: maybe ask on ffmpeg-user ML?